# Fancybox 2 as a link only fires once

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I have the following code:

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.attachbox").fancybox({
            fitToView: false,
            autoSize: true,
            closeClick: false,
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            minWidth: 750,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    css: {
                        'background': 'rgba(153, 204, 255, .5)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<h3>My Products</h3>
<a style="display: none;" class="attachbox fancybox.ajax" href="../site_vendor/add_products.php?page=addproducts"></a>
<div style="text-align:right; padding-top:5px; padding-right:5px;">
    <input class="button"  value="Add a Product" onclick='$("a.attachbox").trigger("click");' />
</div>
```

I've been trying for hours but can't figure out why the above link only fires once. The fancybox opens and once I close it, I can't get the link to open the fancybox again. Everything fails silently, nothing happens on the page and nothing happens in firebug. I'm not sure if it is fancybox 2 related or jquery related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works :

```
<input class="button"  value="Add a Product" onclick='$("a.attachbox").trigger("click");' />

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a.attachbox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: true,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    minWidth: 750,
    helpers: {
      overlay: {
        css: {
          'background': 'rgba(153, 204, 255, .5)'
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

... see **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ESxCN/)** so I don't think is a fancybox or jQuery related issue.

My bet is that after you open the ajax page, somehow a js error is generated (easy to spot if you use the web developer tool bar in Firefox) and that error prevents fancybox to work again. But that is just a guess but hard to say without a link to the actual page.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I finally figured it out. I was loading JQuery on the main page and also loading JQuery again on the AJAX page which disabled certain things on the parent page. Hopes this helps somebody else. Thx again!

Comment: @Dev Newb That helped me out, the second loading of jQuery will override the $.fancybox method that has been instantiated on the original page, and the console will show a "has no method 'fancybox' error"